# How to create a class instance within a function?

Tags: python, function, class

**My code**

```
# Import class Parser from parser.py
from parser import Parser 

from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def main(id):
    ... 
    url = 'test_url.com'
    Parser = Parser()
    Parser.get_response(url)
    Parser.get_beautifulsoup()
    ...

ids = [id for id in range(1, 100)]

p = Pool(20)
p.map(main, ids)
```

**Problem**

I need to call the class `Parser` within the `main()` function, but I have an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Parser' referenced before assignment`.

**Question**

How can I correctly call the `Parser` class inside the `main()`?

Comment: You are overriding the class with the instance, rename `Parser` to `parser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...don't name your instance the same as the class. Do something like:

```
my_Parser = Parser()
```